# How to upload an Excel file (.xlxs) from Angular front end to Laravel API?

Tags: angular, laravel

My process starts in this HTML form:

```
<form [formGroup]="fileForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input
    type="file"
    accept=".xlsx"
    formControlName="file"
    (change)="onFileChange($event.target.files)"
  />
</form>
```

When a file is selected, `onFileChange()` is called, which does the following:

```
public onFileChange(files: FileList): void {
  if (files.length) {
    this.file = files[0];
  }
}
```

Once the file is set, the user clicks the upload button:

```
public onUploadClick(): void {
  if (this.file) {
    this.fileService.uploadFile(this.file).subscribe();
  }
}
```

My `fileService` then handles sending the http request to the API:

```
public uploadFile(file: File): Observable<APIResponse> {
  const url = `${environment.apiURL}/api/other/upload`;

  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("file", file, file.name);

  return this.http.post<APIResponse>(url, { formData });
}
```

Finally, the code in my `FileController`:

```
public function upload(Request $request)
{
    dd($request->all()); // Shows as [ "formData" => [] ]

    $file = $request->file('file');
    dd($file); // Shows as null
}
```

Sorry for the wall of code, but wanted to give you a clear insight into how it currently works.

From what I've found online, using `FormData` is the right thing to do. I'm pretty sure that part is working correctly, because if I do `console.log(formData.get("file"));`, it displays the file.

I've also seen a lot about the content-type header. I've tried setting this to `undefined`, `application/json`, and also `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` (this is the type of the file when it's logged in the console).

On the Laravel side of things, whichever way I try to print the file, it always comes through as `[]` or `null`.

Also, there are no errors produced from either Angular or Laravel.

For some context, I'm trying to import the spreadsheet to then use Laravel Excel (https://docs.laravel-excel.com/), so I can import the contents of the spreadsheet into a database (so please let me know if there's an easier way to get to that stage!)

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else runs into this issue, the problem wasn't with the code above.

Turns out it was an issue with my Nginx config file - I had to add

`client_max_body_size 0;`

to my sites-available config file. This removed the default body size limits, which were causing any files larger than 1mb to not come through to the API.